# Importar tag para html com Flask

Tags: html, python, json, flask, html-tags

Tem como importar uma tag html de um json sem que ela seja convertida? (O projeto usa Flask)
JSON file:

```js
{
  "tag": "<li>teste</li>"
}
```

html puro

```html
<ul>
  {{ tag }}
</ul>
```

html desejado

```html
<ul>
  <li>teste</li>
</ul>
```

html obtido

```html
<ul>
  &lt;li&gt;teste&lt;/li&gt;
</ul>
```

Comment: Use o `{% autoescape off %}
{{ tag }}
{% endautoescape %}`